# TypeScript changing the type while keeping the generic parameters

Tags: typescript

I want to map DTOs (JSON coming from an API) to classes.
The DTOs are generic and I want to preserve those generics while mapping them to classes.

The problem comes up when I have an array of DTOs which may have different generic parameters and I want to map this to an array of class instances.

What would be the correct type used in the constructor below to express that this array consists of `PropertyDTO`s which have the same generic parameters as the `Property`s defined in `TProperty` of the `Template` class?

```
export type SimpleValue = string | number | boolean | Date | null;

export type PropertyDto<TKey extends string, TValue extends SimpleValue> = {
  [K in TKey]: TValue;
}

export class Property<TKey extends string, TValue extends SimpleValue> {
  [K in TKey]!: TValue;

  public constructor(dto: PropertyDto<TKey, TValue>) {
    Object.assign(this, dto);
  }
}

export interface TemplateDto<TProperties extends PropertyDto<string, SimpleValue>[]> {
  properties: TProperties;
}

export class Template<TProperties extends Property<string, SimpleValue>[]> {
  public properties: TProperties;

  public constructor(properties: PropertyDto<string, SimpleValue>[]) { // What would be the correct type here?
    this.properties = properties.map(p => new Property(p));
  }
}
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKBLAtmANsANQENcBXVAXjgGcYoMA7AczgB84HSsAjYKNuNwgR8RBgIAiRGKnadcuANwAoZaEiwEyVAAUoEFLEQSYEADwAVANLBEcUDIYATajTqMmAGjgXiZVA7Azq6YOPh+5AB8cADeynBwANpWcIw+NogAugBcPhHAKgC+qurQ8ADGuETUrnoGfEiWGfYgji5u9MzeviTkLW0h2HiEvcDRcQnJqeLWtpkAhLk9-irxcGCk3LgY5XDlEAy0UKTlplAAFE6muXWGSCbms4jd+ZEAlLFrCQDy3ABWwFOADpqtQMEwGOcYAALDDUbxXCBvFQJYrFNTgMrTGRQABmRHKqAswDC0mAD0stwaGGArkCwTgVKMFKOHm8oWGr0SmXGazA+juNOoSyZMCFRRKmM0lVBPhJeDJlIF1Np-SC7VFiDMrK66CG4VGkW5vISGy2O3WytgQpFVrFtNWps2212+0OdBOZ3O-Pq1tpNztxlM2vcuo5Bv8RsyHxicAA9HG4AB1aHSOAAdwgpFwTkEqBhqH2UCggPgSBQcGhfGAAH4vghYdQgT7BaqqC2VU2sEQwN64BRogxgOnGYHvW9kWs0UA)